# How to make the Toolbar title clickable exactly like on ActionBar, without setting it as ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

### Background

I wish to show an ActionBar on PreferenceActivity, as it's not available for pre-Honeycomb devices (even in the support library).

Because such a class isn't available on the support library, I can't just call "setSupportActionBar" . I also don't wish to use a library (like [**this one**](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment)) since all of the libraries I've found still use Holo style, so they didn't get updated so far, with this in mind.

To do this, I'm trying to mimic the look&feel of the title of the ActionBar into the new [**Toolbar**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) class, that was presented on support library v7 .

### The problem

I've succeeded putting a title and a an "up" button, but I can't find out how to make them clickable like a normal action bar, including the effect of touching.

### The code

Here's the code:

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
  {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    final Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.windowBackgroundColor));
    toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
    toolbar.setClickable(true);
    toolbar.setLogo(getResIdFromAttribute(this,R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator));
    }

  public static int getResIdFromAttribute(final Activity activity,final int attr)
    {
    if(attr==0)
      return 0;
    final TypedValue typedvalueattr=new TypedValue();
    activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr,typedvalueattr,true);
    return typedvalueattr.resourceId;
    }
  }
```

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.antonioleiva.materialeverywhere.SettingsActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/abs__ab_solid_shadow_holo" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### What I've tried

I've tried all of the click listeners types of the Toolbar class, but none helped.

The only thing that almost worked is to use "setNavigationIcon" instead of "setLogo", but that actually makes the title&icon being clicakable, yet only the icon shows its effect of being clicked (even if I click on the title).

### The question

How can I add the look & feel of the Toolbar, to have the title & logo of it to look like the ActionBar?

Comment: I ended up by leaving the real ActionBar where it is (in the one only Activity I have) and **simulating** the PreferenceScreen. Now this is actually just another Fragment in which I **recreate the look and feel** of the standard PreferenceActivity elements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just remember that the Toolbar is basically just a ViewGroup so you can add a TextView to it and listen to onClick events like that.

Add TextView to Toolbar in XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Listen for clicks in your Activity:

```
toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Clicked");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want it to look like the normal actionbar that I use on other activities, and maybe be able to add an actionItem (for a different preferenceActivity that I use for widgets). You can try out my app if it's hard to imagine it : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager . About clicking on the text, I've now noticed that this has changed in material design, and only the "up" button should be clickable, but in the current approach the title is clickable (yet as I said, doesn't have an effect of clicking) and I can't make it un-clickable

Comment: So you question is about how to make the text look more like the Actionbar text and not be clickable?

Comment: Yes, preferably making it entirely look and behave like a normal ActionBar. If it's impossible to make the textView un-clickable, at least set it the same effect of clicking like on the "up" button.

Comment: On what device is it clickable?

Comment: on mine: SGS3 (I9300) with custom rom CM (Android 4.4.x) . When I click on the title, the "up" button also gets clicked (or at least has an effect of being clicked).

Comment: Weird, the first part of my answer does not result in the title being clickable on 4.4.x, and 2.3.x so it might be a CM thing. If you're using the first half of my answer and still getting a clickable Title what you can do is instead of using the title, add a TextView to the Toolbar layout (like I did in the second half of my answer) and listen for onClick events on that fake title then just finish the activity on title click.

Comment: I've now tested your code. I have no idea what is different but it works, but why did you set both logo and icon? the navigation icon is enough. also, BTW, you can set the style of the toolbar to be as of an action bar: app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" , as shown here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html . This way, you can avoid all the customizations stuff (colors etc). Really odd that I can't reproduce the problem though.

Comment: Anyway, because of the doubt, I tick your answer. I am sorry for all the hassle.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that you can add menu items even if it's not a real actionbar, by calling "getMenu", and handle it just as if you've called it via "onCreateOptionsMenu"

Comment: Yes, there's also a `inflateMenu` method that inflates the menu for you

Comment: ok, I've made a library having this missing part of the support library, including material dialogs too: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialStuffLibrary

Comment: What if I use an entire layout as toolbar child? I'm trying to inflate it, and add it as child with addChild() method. Then, I set clickListeners on the views contained in the inflated layout, but this events are never called. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @jem88 Your comment would be better suited as a question. If you cannot find a similar one on Stack Overflow then feel free to create one

Comment: @MrEngineer13: It's not working for me, when i setOnClickListener to custom view Toolbar

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and found a quite convenient way for it (for the clickable title), doing this with the `Toolbar`. It does not matter, if the `Toolbar`is used as `ActionBar` or not, it works for both cases.

Just set the click listener on the `Toolbar` itself, this will result in the complete `Toolbar`firing the click listener, if not a menu item or the home icon is clicked. For me, that's exactly what I expect...

For example:

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getThis(), "Toolbar title clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

`onOptionsItemSelected`, home click and similar *WON'T* fire the `onClick` event. Seems like a good solution

Comment: Wouldn't it get fired when clicking on empty spaces in the toolbar?

Comment: It will, but that space would be filled by a textview with `MATCH_PARENT` as well... it's fine for my usecases...

Comment: @prom85 how do you add the textview with h match_parent? if I add a view with match_parent it will cover the title.

Comment: I did this as I wanted to use this text view instead of a title . If you don't need the text view don't use it? Or do you need it?

Comment: This is a great solution. There is no need to add anything to the xml for the toolbar, i.e. no need for `TextView` or `ImageView`. What I did was to set a logo with `getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.jclogo);`, make it clickable: `toolbar.setClickable(true);`, followed by the code above and it works perfect. Thank you @prom85

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it pretty easily without having to do any workarounds. You just need to cycle through all the child views of the `Toolbar`, and find a `TextView` that's got the correct title text.

```
String title = toolbar.getTitle();
for(int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
    View tmpView = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
    if("android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView".equals(tmpView.getClass().getName())){
        if(((AppCompatTextView) tmpView).getText().equals(title)){
            tmpView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //do whatever you want here
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing values (text title in this case) is usually a bad idea because the title can change, and because multiple elements might have the same value, or the title can be an empty string.

Comment: That's not a problem. We're checking the title right before cycling through the views, so the title would have to change in the spit-second between those 2 actions, and that's virtually never gonna happen

Answer (score 1):

After setting up not empty toolbar title try this for setting title click listener

```
    if (toolbarView != null) {
        int childCount = toolbarView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View view = toolbarView.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                view.setOnClickListener(listener);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and after setting up not empty toolbar subtitle for setting subtitle click listener

```
    if (toolbarView != null) {
        int childCount = toolbarView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View view = toolbarView.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                view.setOnClickListener(listener);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```