# Make toolbar title clickable and respond to it

Tags: android, toolbar

I would like the user to be able to tap the title in the toolbar and perform an action when it does:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the Toolbar title clickable exactly like on ActionBar, without setting it as ActionBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495530/how-to-make-the-toolbar-title-clickable-exactly-like-on-actionbar-without-setti)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Toolbar as replacement for the ActionBar, the title is not clickable. You can  `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` which will display the back arrow and handle the click in `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
  Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(tb);
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test");
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Click

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Alternatively, since the ToolBar is a ViewGroup, you could host a `TextView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and programmatically you can register a `View.OnClickListener`. E.g.

```
Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(tb);
tb.findViewById(R.id.title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

Comment: Can I replace the icon?

Comment: it should be possible with `toolBar.setNavigationIcon`

Comment: Can I change the size of the new icon? whether in the MainActivity.java or in the layout file.

Comment: Could you make a small effort and just try?